# Android : How to Check if incoming SMS number exist in contact phone in BroadcastReceiver and block is number not exist

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver

I want to be when there is incoming sms whose number is not in contact, then the text in the block, for sure by checking whether there are any number is not in the phone book.
i am have a code check number exist, but error time i code move in class BroadcastReceiver?, and how to call method contactExists in onReceive?

```
 public boolean contactExists(Context context, String number, ContentResolver contentResolver) {
            Cursor phones = contentResolver.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.
                    CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME + " ASC");
            while (phones.moveToNext()){
                String phoneNumber = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                if(PhoneNumberUtils.compare(number, phoneNumber)){
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
```

I use AsyncTask, but I am confused about what to call the method contactExists, and how do I enter the number into contactExists, in order to recognize that the number of existing

```
public class SmsReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    public static int MSG_TPE = 0;
    private String number;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        String action = intent.getAction();
        if (action.equals(AppConstants.SMS_RECEIVED_ACTION)) {
            Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
            SmsMessage[] msgs = null;
            String message = "";
            String date = AppUtils.getDate();
            String time = AppUtils.getTime();
            String status = AppUtils.getStatus();
            if (bundle != null) {
                Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
                msgs = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];
                for (int i = 0; i < msgs.length; i++) {
                    msgs[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[i]);
                    number = msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress();
                    message += msgs[i].getMessageBody().toString();
                    message += "\n";
                }
                if (SettingsPreferences.isBlockAllSms(context)) {
                    this.abortBroadcast();

                    CallMessageItem item = new CallMessageItem();
                    item.setDate(date);
                    item.setMessage(message);
                    item.setNumber(number);
                    item.setTime(time);
                    item.setStatus(status);
                    item.setType(AppConstants.TYPE_MESSAGE);
                    CMBDataProvider.addCallMessage(context, item);

                    if (SettingsPreferences.isNotificationShow(context)) {
                        AppUtils.generateNotification(
                                context,
                                context.getResources().getString(
                                        R.string.block_sms_message), false);

                    }


                } else if (SettingsPreferences.isBlockPrivateSms(context)) {
                    ArrayList<BlockItem> block_number = CMBDataProvider
                            .getBlackList(context);
                    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(message)
                            && !TextUtils.isEmpty(number)
                            && block_number != null && block_number.size() > 0) {
                        message = message.trim();
                        for (int i = 0; i < block_number.size(); i++) {
                            if (number
                                    .contains(block_number.get(i).getNumber())) {
                                this.abortBroadcast();
                                CallMessageItem item = new CallMessageItem();
                                item.setDate(date);
                                item.setMessage(message);
                                item.setNumber(number);
                                item.setTime(time);
                                item.setType(AppConstants.TYPE_MESSAGE);
                                CMBDataProvider.addCallMessage(context, item);
                                if (SettingsPreferences
                                        .isNotificationShow(context)) {
                                    AppUtils.generateNotification(
                                            context,
                                            context.getResources().getString(
                                                    R.string.block_sms_message),
                                            false);
                                }
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private class Contactexixt extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Double> {

        @Override
        protected Double doInBackground(String... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            contactExists(params[0]);
            return null;
        }

        public boolean contactExists(Context context, String number){
            Uri lookupUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI, Uri.encode(number));

            String[] mPhoneNumberProjection = { ContactsContract.PhoneLookup._ID, ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.NUMBER, ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME };

            Cursor cur = context.getContentResolver().query(lookupUri,mPhoneNumberProjection, null, null, null);

            try {
                // Add your data

            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            }
        }


    }


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not query content provider in main thread, run a new thread or use AsyncTask.

```
private class Checkcontact extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {

    private Context context;

    public Checkcontact(Context context) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... strings) {
        try {
            return contactExists(context, strings[0]);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return false;
    }

    // The argument result is return by method doInBackground
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        // You can handle the result here
    }

    public boolean contactExists(Context context, String number) throws Exception {
        Uri lookupUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI, Uri.encode(number));

        String[] mPhoneNumberProjection = { ContactsContract.PhoneLookup._ID, ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.NUMBER,
                ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME };

        Cursor cur = context.getContentResolver().query(lookupUri, mPhoneNumberProjection, null, null, null);
        try {
            if (cur.moveToFirst()) {
                // if contact are in contact list it will return true
                return true;
            }
        } finally {
            if (cur != null)
                cur.close();
        }
        // if contact are not match that means contact are not added
        return false;
    }
}
```

Start a task:

```
new Checkcontact(context).execute("123456789");
```

Comment: sorry I accidentally edit your comment, I think it's a question of me, can you check again your comments, whether it is correct

Comment: i have error:
Error:(95, 6) error: constructor Checkcontact in class SmsReceiver.Checkcontact cannot be applied to given types;
required: Context
found: SmsReceiver
reason: actual argument SmsReceiver cannot be converted to Context by method invocation conversion

Comment: Oh sorry, in BroadcastReceiver the argument pass to task is the argument "context" of method onReceive.

Comment: Can you help me, to be able to function?

Comment: the program of work, when I call in activity onReceive, and I use the "if"
how i uses the "if" if the numbers in the phone book right then run another Aktivity?

Comment: If you need to start another activity to handle the number, start the activity and pass the argument, like the block number.